# How to Create Pretty URL?

Tags: php, html, pretty-urls

What is the simplest way to set up pretty url such as:

Before: www.example.com/aboutus/senior_management.php
After: www.example.com/aboutus/senior-management/

How is the file management like and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for url rewriting.
if you use apache as web server you can find a great tutorial here on [smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)